# Jtwig Current date function shows bad month number

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jtwig

I would like to display current date on my site using Twig. The problem is `{{ "now"|date("Y-m-d") }}` function which display me random month number like "**2020-16-17**". Every time when I rerun my Spring Boot program, the function shows different month number.

Comment: But I'm using Twig with Java Spring Boot :)

Comment: I see now, perhaps it's better to remove the twig tag then to avoid confussion :)

Comment: I would post that as answer btw instead of placing it as an update

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by change `{{ "now"|date("Y-m-d") }}` to `{{ "now"|date("Y-MM-d") }}`, "m" was showing minutes. Of course it is solution for Java.

Comment: Is uppercase `Y` correct then? In Java you would need either lowercase `y` or `u`.